# Reorder or remove out-of-order epochs in Rinex file

Tags: rinex

I have some Rinex (2.11) files where something went wrong and every epoch is duplicated. Mostly they're in order, but sometimes there's an epoch out of order, like this:

AABBCCDDEFEFGGHHIIJJKLKLMMNN...

Is there a tool that can reorder or discard out-of-order epochs? Teqc will abort when it hits an out-of-order epoch, but will fix duplicates as long as they're adjacent. So far I've manually deleted the OOO epochs but that's rather tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GFZRNX software now discards out-of-order epochs, solving this problem.

http://semisys.gfz-potsdam.de/semisys/scripts/download/